# Spark dataframe to nested JSON

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataframe `joinDf` created from joining the following four dataframes on `userId`:

```
val detailsDf = Seq((123,"first123","xyz"))
                .toDF("userId","firstName","address")


val emailDf = Seq((123,"abc@gmail.com"),
                  (123,"def@gmail.com"))
              .toDF("userId","email")


val foodDf = Seq((123,"food2",false,"Italian",2),
                 (123,"food3",true,"American",3),
                 (123,"food1",true,"Mediterranean",1))
            .toDF("userId","foodName","isFavFood","cuisine","score")


val gameDf = Seq((123,"chess",false,2),
                 (123,"football",true,1))
             .toDF("userId","gameName","isOutdoor","score")

val joinDf = detailsDf
            .join(emailDf, Seq("userId"))
            .join(foodDf, Seq("userId"))
            .join(gameDf, Seq("userId"))
```

`User`'s food and game favorites should be ordered by score in the ascending order.

I am trying to create a result from this `joinDf` where the JSON looks like the following:

```
[
  {
  "userId": "123",
  "firstName": "first123",
  "address": "xyz",
  "UserFoodFavourites": [
    {
     "foodName": "food1",
     "isFavFood": "true",
     "cuisine": "Mediterranean",
    },
    {
     "foodName": "food2",
     "isFavFood": "false",
     "cuisine": "Italian",
    },
    {
     "foodName": "food3",
     "isFavFood": "true",
     "cuisine": "American",
    }
   ]
   "UserEmail": [
     "abc@gmail.com",
     "def@gmail.com"
   ]
   "UserGameFavourites": [
     {
      "gameName": "football",
      "isOutdoor": "true"
     },
     {
      "gameName": "chess",
      "isOutdoor": "false"
     }
   ]
  }
]
```

Should I use `joinDf.groupBy().agg(collect_set())`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is based on the answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580253/collect-list-by-preserving-order-based-on-another-variable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995376/apache-spark-window-function-with-nested-column)

It uses the Window function. It shows how to create a nested list of food preferences for a given `userid` based on the food score. Here we are creating a `struct` of `FoodDetails` from the columns we have

```
val foodModifiedDf = foodDf.withColumn("FoodDetails",
                            struct("foodName","isFavFood", "cuisine","score"))
                            .drop("foodName","isFavFood", "cuisine","score")

println("Just printing the food detials here")
foodModifiedDf.show(10, truncate = false)
```

Here we are creating a Windowing function which will accumulate the list for a `userId` based on the `FoodDetails.score` in descending order. The windowing function when applied goes on accumulating the list as it encounters new rows with same `userId`. After we have done accumulating, we have to do a `groupBy`  over the `userId` to select the largest list.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window


val window = Window.partitionBy("userId").orderBy( desc("FoodDetails.score"))

val userAndFood = detailsDf.join(foodModifiedDf, "userId")

val newUF  = userAndFood.select($"*", collect_list("FoodDetails").over(window) as "FDNew")

println(" UserAndFood dataframe after windowing function applied")
newUF.show(10, truncate = false)

val resultUF = newUF.groupBy("userId")
                  .agg(max("FDNew"))

println("Final result after select the maximum length list")
resultUF.show(10, truncate = false)
```

This is how the result looks like finally :

```
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|userId|max(FDNew)                                                                               |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|123   |[[food3, true, American, 3], [food2, false, Italian, 2], [food1, true, Mediterranean, 1]]|
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Given this dataframe, it should be easier to write out the nested json.

Comment: In this solution how will you carry over **"firstName","address"** columns from the **detailsDf** into **resultDF** ?

Comment: In the aggregation, you can use `newUF.groupBy("userId").agg(max("FDNew"), first(firstName), first(address))`

Comment: So basically groupBy after join is used to dedupe records after join had caused it. And more joins will add extra duplication and extra work to the executors.

Comment: Read the question properly. We need the food preferences to be sorted by the `score`. That's what the Window function does here. You can run the code and see the results yourself.

Comment: Indeed, I missed it, it was quite late in the night when I was doing it, thank you for pointing out and I have updated my answer with a quick fix and got the desired output and avoided the extra load on the executors.

Comment: BTW, I do not doubt the correctness of the output of your solution, just pointing out performance considerations.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of joining before grouping and collecting lists is the fact that join will produce a lot of records for group by to collapse, in your example it is 12 records after join and before groupby, also you would need to worry about picking **"firstName","address"** out **detailsDf** out of 12 duplicates. To avoid both problems your could pre-process the food, email and game dataframes using struct and groupBy and join them to the **detailsDf** with no risk of exploding your data due to multiple records with the same **userId** in the joined tables.

```
val detailsDf = Seq((123,"first123","xyz"))
            .toDF("userId","firstName","address")


val emailDf = Seq((123,"abc@gmail.com"),
              (123,"def@gmail.com"))
          .toDF("userId","email")


val foodDf = Seq((123,"food2",false,"Italian",2),
             (123,"food3",true,"American",3),
             (123,"food1",true,"Mediterranean",1))
        .toDF("userId","foodName","isFavFood","cuisine","score")


val gameDf = Seq((123,"chess",false,2),
             (123,"football",true,1))
         .toDF("userId","gameName","isOutdoor","score")

val emailGrp = emailDf.groupBy("userId").agg(collect_list("email").as("UserEmail"))

val foodGrp = foodDf
          .select($"userId", struct("score", "foodName","isFavFood","cuisine").as("UserFoodFavourites"))
          .groupBy("userId").agg(sort_array(collect_list("UserFoodFavourites")).as("UserFoodFavourites"))

val gameGrp = gameDf
          .select($"userId", struct("gameName","isOutdoor","score").as("UserGameFavourites"))
          .groupBy("userId").agg(collect_list("UserGameFavourites").as("UserGameFavourites"))

val result = detailsDf.join(emailGrp, Seq("userId"))
        .join(foodGrp, Seq("userId"))
        .join(gameGrp, Seq("userId"))

result.show(100, false)
```

Output:

```
+------+---------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|userId|firstName|address|UserEmail                     |UserFoodFavourites                                                                       |UserGameFavourites                      |
+------+---------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|123   |first123 |xyz    |[abc@gmail.com, def@gmail.com]|[[1, food1, true, Mediterranean], [2, food2, false, Italian], [3, food3, true, American]]|[[chess, false, 2], [football, true, 1]]|
+------+---------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

As all **groupBy** are done on **userId** and joins as well, spark will optimise it quite well.

**UPDATE 1**: After @user238607 pointed out that I have missed the original requirement of food preferences being sorted by score, did a quick fix and placed the *score* column as first element of structure *UserFoodFavourites* and used **sort_array** function to arrange data in desired order without forcing extra shuffle operation. Updated the code and its output.